# Some help using my values read from a file in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, vector, coordinates

I'm having some problems with my program I'm trying to write and I'm hoping someone could give a little bit of guidance as to how to deal with the issues I'm facing...

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct City
{
string name;
int x;
int y;
};

int main()
{
vector<City>Coord;

City entries[10];

ifstream fin("Locations.txt");

int nb_entries;

string name;

int x, y;

for(nb_entries = 0; fin.good() && nb_entries < 10; nb_entries++)

{

    fin >> entries[nb_entries].name;

    fin >> entries[nb_entries].x;

    fin >> entries[nb_entries].y;

    cout << "City: " << entries[nb_entries].name << ", ";

    cout << "x: " << entries[nb_entries].x << ", ";

    cout << "y: " << entries[nb_entries].y << ", " << endl;

}   

system("pause");

return 0;
```

}

This reads my coordinates that I have stored in a text file and outputs them to the screen. The text file is formatted like:

city1 x1 y1

city2 x2 y2

...

city10 x10 y10

And the output at this stage was so that I could see whether my code was working. What I need to do now is to use these coordinates after getting input from the user choosing the cities. I have tried reading the coordinates into an array and a vector but I am struggling to find the best way to store them as values and call them later in the program. I am still new to programming and C++ so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a map from city names to coordinate pairs like below:

```
#include <unordered_map>

unordered_map<string, pair<int,int> >    myMap;
```

You can put your data into `myMap` like this:

```
myMap[cityName] = make_pair(x,y);
```

and can recall them like this:

```
x = myMap[cityName].first;
y = myMap[cityName].second;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have never used maps before, how does that last bit work? Is it saying to read the first integer in the file to x, and the second to y, and then loop? I have tried putting it in and although it compiles there is no sensible output from it, I have probably misunderstood something!

Comment: Also how would I call the coordinates for a given city later in the program considering the cities aren't initialised in the program, as they are stored in a file?

Comment: The coordinates store as a pair    `pair<int, int> coordinate`     and you can read x and y  as     `coordinate.first`   and    `coordinate.second`.    `myMap` maps the city name to a `coordinate`.    If the city name doesn't exist in the map it will return nothing.